# Bash - How to read content of file into variable, the file was read from key->value property file?

Tags: bash, shell

I have one key->value property file (my.prop) with such a content:

```
ROOT_PATH = /opt/user1/
REL_PATH = data/folder1/
CONF_FILENAME = my.conf
```

In my bash script I simply read this file, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROP_FILE='my.prop'
ROOT_PATH =''
REL_PATH=''
CONF_FILENAME=''

while read -r key eq value; do
    case $key in
      "ROOT_PATH") 
        ROOT_PATH=${value}
      ;;
    case $key in
      "REL_PATH") 
        REL_PATH=${value}
      ;;
    case $key in
      "CONF_FILENAME") 
        CONF_FILENAME=${value}
      ;;
    esac
done < $PROP_FILE
```

After that I would like to form the path to *my.conf* file and read its content to some variable, like this:

```
CONF_FULL_PATH=$ROOT_PATH$REL_PATH$CONF_FILENAME
CONF_FILE_CONTENT=`cat ${CONF_FULL_PATH}`
```

If I print out `CONF_FULL_PATH` variable it will have some trash inside (parts of all three sub paths). 
And at this line`` CONF_FILE_CONTENT=`cat ${CONF_FULL_PATH}` `` I will have this error message - *: No such file or directoryta/folder1/*

So, my question is, how could I properly form the path to *my.conf* file and put its content to some specific variable? I already tried `source` command as a replacement for while loop. Also to build a proper path string I've used this statements:
`$(dirname $ROOT_PATH)/$(dirname REL_PATH)/$(basename $CONF_FILENAME)` but this looks odd for my point of view.

Any help would be great!

Comment: `while read -r key eq value; do declare "$key=$value"; done < $PROP_FILE` simplifies your loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the spaces from your `my.prop` file, you can use `source` (or `.`) to read the variables inside it. This will make it much easier.

my.prop:

```
ROOT_PATH=/opt/user1/
REL_PATH=data/folder1/
CONF_FILENAME=my.conf
```

Then you can use these directly in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. my.prop
CONF_FULL_PATH="${ROOT_PATH}${REL_PATH}${CONF_FILENAME}"
CONF_FILE_CONTENT=$(cat "$CONF_FULL_PATH")
```

Comment: `tr -s ' =' = my.prop > my.prop.clean`

Comment: Concerning dot operator, a dot/period **.** is a synonym for `source` which I also tried. The problem is how to make a valid **path** based on strings that were read from a property file.
The main point is that: if I print `CONF_FULL_PATH` after concatenation like this:
`echo $CONF_FULL_PATH` 
the output will be:
_my.conflder1/_ which is not correct, somehow it was interpret incorrectly and `$(cat "$CONF_FULL_PATH")` will print _my.conf: No such file or directory_.

Comment: Is the output of `echo $CONF_FULL_PATH` incorrect even if you use braces around the names of the variables you are concatenating?